# I would like to run a query to produce a price list for each customer and product taking into consideration promotional prices and discount prices?

Tags: sql, epicorerp, epicor

We have a number of different promotions (fixed prices and discount %) for each customer.  I want to be able to produce an extract so that we can work out what the price the customer would pay if they were entering a Sales Order direct within Epicor. I then want to use this as part on an internal portal so I will store these prices in a seperate table.

I can extract each item individually i.e. customers & products. but I can't seem to get the logic correct for working out the correct sales price.

This is for Epicor 9.05
Thanks

Comment: Can you post a snippet of code that you tried and did not work? What is your calculation, what was the result, and what was the expected result? Need more information to assist

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use customer price lists to track pricing for your customers.  This will allow you to set discounts or custom prices for some or all of your parts.

While the material is proprietary to Epicor, you can take a look at the "Customers and Accounts Receivable" chapter of the EpicorAppplication_UserGuide for your version as found on your [EpicWeb](https://epicweb.epicor.com/Support/MyEPICweb/Pages/default.aspx) customer portal for more information on using these.